# centering text using .format the right way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want this:

```
============================= thread: 1 starting ==============================
```

the only way to achieve this with the .format method that I found is:

```
print("{:=^79}".format(' Thread: ' + self.thread_id + ' starting '))
```

is there a better way to do this? since this is a bit hard to read and kinda goes against the whole .format principle of having string on the left and values on the right.

Comment: @FelixLahmer Yeah I'm aware of this, however my question is it possible to do it using .format without breaking the whole purpose of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Felix Lahmer has pointed out, you can use `center`:

```
>>> ' Thread: {} starting '.format(42).center(79, '=')
'============================= Thread: 42 starting ============================='
```

Or you could nest `format`.

```
>>> '{:=^79}'.format(' Thread: {} starting '.format(42))
'============================= Thread: 42 starting ============================='
```

Comment: Alright, I thought I was missing something regarding the first {}. I guess it's not as complex as it seems.